# How to discretize this equation

Tags: analysis

I have a problem I would like some advice with. I have to discretize a parabolic PDE. There are two parts, first part I would just like someone to check my work - second part I need some help with

The PDE is Ut + aUx = DUxx+ cU + S(x,t)

I have to discretize using the classic method. I got (1/dt)(Uin+1 - Uin) + (aUni+1 - Uni-1)/(2dx) = (D/dx2)(Uni-1 - 2Uni + Uni+1) + CUi + Sni

The second part of the problem is discretizing a right boundary condition DUx(b,t) = K(U(b,t) - Ub) using the BD2

The right boundary needs to be discretized at x=b as xN so that the discrete equation involves UNn+1, UN-1n+1, and UN-2n+1

Any help is appreciated. Please don't just give me the answer. I want to understand what on earth is going on. Thanks!